# How to stop mediaplayer when i click to leave the app?

Tags: java, android

I have started a sound in onCreate method meaning when I open the app the music starts playing. Then I have a button to stop the music and it's ok. But if I start the app then leave the app the music stills playing so I want to stop the music too when I click the back button to leave the app.
I have this code:

onCreate:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.seconds);
mp.start();
```

Then onDestroy:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.stop;
    }
```

But in mp.stop; i have mp in red so isn't working. 
If i try to put MediaPlayer mp outside onCreate then the mp.start; and mp.stop; mp turn blues and don't work too.

Any advice?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Android Studio

Comment: I haven't used Android Studio till now, but maybe you can tell what does a "Blue Line" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
>  MediaPlayer mp;    
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     //other codes
>     mp  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.seconds);
>     mp.prepare();
>     mp.start();
> }
> protected void onDestroy() {    
>     //other codes
>     mp.stop();
>  }
> }
> ```

try to use like above..

Answer (score 1):

You can play song using this function

```
public void playSong()
    {

        try 
        {
            mp.reset();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Then on destroy just release the player

```
 @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private MediaPlayer mp; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ///
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.seconds);
   }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
         if(mp.isPlaying()){
              mp.stop();
         }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put following code in Activity's onStop() method so that when your activity goes in backstack or you leave the app, the music will be stopped.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
     if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
     {
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
     }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SampleMediaPlayer extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_media_player); //your layout resource
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

}

Comment: add some description so other might follow.